# Workflow clearification on OSGi Servlet and HTML UI

Tags: ajax, servlets, user-interface, osgi, frontend

I need some clearification on the Workflow with OSGi Servlets and HTML Frontend. I am an old school HTML and Javascript programmer and new to all this OSGi, Ajax and JQuery stuff. I am working on an own OSGi server implementation. I created my OSGi Plugin with eclipse following this guide: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Creating+a+new+OSGi+Bundle+using+Eclipse

My Servlet is working perfectly fine so far. It is supposed to handle Database Requests. I coded a Website with HTML and Javascript(JQuery) from which I want to fire Ajax Requests to the Servlet.

My Problem is, that I have no idea how to integrate my HTML/Javascript/JQuery stuff into the OSGi Servlet. I tried to register it as resources within the Servlet Bundle, which worked fine but I'm not sure if this is a very elegant way... It needs to run on the same OSGi Server, but does it need to be in the same Bundle as the Servlet or in its own?

Which kind of project would I create in eclipse for the UI Bundle and how would I export it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to make your web resources (html, javascript and css files) available on a url. You could do this manually by hand with a Servlet. If you package the web resources in the bundle, you can get an InputStream to those resources from the BundleContext.getBundle().

An easier approach is to use the Amdatu ResourceHandler. This is a so called "extender" that has the sole purpose of making resources from bundles available on an url.

You need to do the following:
1) Make sure that your resources are packaged in the bundle
2) Add two extra headers to the manifest of the bundle that contains the resources
X-Web-Resource-Version: 1.0
X-Web-Resource: path/to/resources
3) Add the Apache Felix Whiteboard and Amdatu ResourceHandler bundles to your runtime.

Documentation can be found on the Amdatu website: http://amdatu.org/components/web.html (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

The Pax Web project might be of interest for you, anyway there is a [sample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/helloworld-wc) on how to publish resources available. 
This sample should also work similar HTTP-Services like Apache Felix HTTP-Service, probably needs some minor tweaks :) .